# the size of std::map is greater then amount of elements shown in the debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, dictionary, size

How can it happen that the number of elements shown in the debugger of VC2010 is less than the size of the map?I have 137 elements and it shows me only 100.When I use printf it prints them all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems there is a limit of 100 items shown in the debugger. The service pack 1 increase this limit to 2000 :

Details on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/537218/only-100-std-map-elements-in-debugger)